# "a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected"

Tags: c#, .net

A user is receiving "a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected" error message when trying to log in. I set validateRequest="false" in the logon.aspx page as well as the following in the "location" of web.config:

```
<location path="~/Account/Logon.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

User still getting the error message. I askded what special characters he has in his password and he has "&", "#" and "(", none of which should generate this error (I have # and * in mine). Is there anything else I can try?

Almost all suggestions to fix this issue, including those at this site, recommend the use of "validaterequest=false" which does not seem to help.

Comment: Is his password `"drop table users"`? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure you can set the `requestValidationMode` for just one location. This changes the whole pipeline for the entire app.

Comment: user id and password are passed to LDAP for authentication. "drop table users" would most probably fail authentication.

Comment: I will move the requestValidationMode out of "location" and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Two parts of solution. At first add to your controller method ValidateInputAttribute:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

The second part is more difficult. You should validate value manually in your code. Ensure that there is no SQL injections in user input.

**UPDATE**
For ASP.NET Web Forms use ValidateRequest tag to your page like in this example:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="LoginForm.aspx.cs" 
ValidateRequest="false" AutoEventWireup="false" 
Inherits="Junk.WebForm1" %>
```

Comment: Thank you Vadim, but this is not an MVC app.

Comment: @NoBullMan huh ok. Did you try to add validateRequest="false" tag in your aspx-page?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually the user just informed me that when he changed his password that included "&" and "#" by changing the order from "&#" to "#&", he was able to log in with no errors. So, there is something about "&#" that generates this error even though I have specified "validateRequest=false".

Comment: @NoBullMan do you have code like next one? var password = Request.Form["password"]; 
Try to change it to var password = Request.Unvalidated("password");

Comment: I don't see Request.Unvalidate() (is not listed in Intellisense).

Comment: Property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx
Iterator https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.unvalidatedrequestvalues.item(v=vs.110).aspx
Extension method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548128(v=vs.111).aspx
If it'll help you I'm updating answer text. And please add correct asp.net tag (forms, mvc or pages) to the question.